# Sitecore Configuration issue

Tags: configuration, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I'm new to Sitecore, (very new) and I'm trying to get an existing project working locally.  All so far so good, apart from the error:

Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster

The references to the this in the config files are:

web.config:

```
 <contentSearch>
  <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="sitecore_dev_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
        <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)"/>
        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/devLuceneIndexConfiguration"/>
        <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
          <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster"/>
        </strategies>
```

And some patch files that do the following:

```
 <indexConfigurations>
    <indexUpdateStrategies>
      <syncMaster>
        <patch:delete />
      </syncMaster>
```

*EDIT* Also in SiteCore.ContentSearch.DefaultConfigurations.config

```
          <syncMaster type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.SynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <param desc="database">master</param>
      </syncMaster>
```

Can someone help me identify what I am looking for here to fix this, as it is not completely obvious

Comment: The error is relating to syncMaster update strategy which you are deleting via the patch. Why are you deleting the syncMaster update strategy? It's required for the Master index

Comment: Not 100% sure whats going on with it, as mentioned taken over the project and tyring to get it building locally.  I think it might be different profile configurations getting mixed into the build. at the moment

Comment: Remove that patch for the time being and see if you get a new error or if it works correctly

Comment: Yea, thats cracked it... The path was in a .environment.config file for a certain profile, and it was breaking the local build.  Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad that's sorted it - I'll add it as a full answer below for others to see in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is stating that it is trying to find the `syncMaster` update strategy as referenced in the `ContentSearch` Configuration file

```
<strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster"/>
```

Your patch config file actively removes the `syncMaster` update strategy from configuration.

```xml
<syncMaster>
    <patch:delete />
</syncMaster>
```

Therefore remove that patch file and the `syncMaster` will stay in config and therefore the error will be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to fixing it. The reason syncMaster could not be found is because it's being deleted with the . Just comment or remove this section from your config file

```
<syncMaster>
    <patch:delete />
</syncMaster>
```

Just to give you a little background.

Sitecore has various strategies on how it indexes content for different indexes. You can read more about them here - http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/04/sitecore-7-index-update-strategies.aspx.

Syncmaster applies to master databases only. CMs (Content Management servers) usually are the only ones that talk to the master database so syncMaster should only exist on CMs. On CDs (Content Delivery servers), Sitecore scalability guide tells you to remove all connections to the master database and so syncMaster becomes irrelevant there and hence you have to patch:delete it.

Let me know how it goes.